# Remove files with the similar name except one?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

[image: The image shows different versions of TR - I want to delete, without deleting any other applications and keeping the latest version of TR 2091.2]

I want to remove all previous versions of Tableau Reader.app  from applications apart from the latest one. I want to do this through command line.  The problem that I am having is I want to remove all files containing `tableau reader` except for the file `tableau reader 2019.2`.

I have tried  multiple ways but they aren't working. I am not very experienced with this. Any help is appreciated. The script below: Checks if the Application is running and if not goes about deleting the different versions(bit I need help on)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

process="$4"
processrunning=$( ps axc | grep "${process}" )

if [ "$processrunning" != "" ] ; then

echo "$process IS running, do nothing" 
echo "error: script failed"

exit 1
else 

echo "$process is not running and will remove the old versions"

find $HOME/Applications/ -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app' | grep "tableau reader" | xargs rm

#rm -r $HOME/Applications/Tableau Reader?*.app![$HOME/Applications/"Tableau Reader 2019.2.app"]

#find. -type f !( -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app') -exec rm -f "Tableau Reader"*.app {} +

fi
```

Comment: Hi, Im not sure how this helps. I searched up the head function and this looks within the file? I want to delete files with the similar name except for one.

Comment: For testing, don't do it within the script, but try one of the posted solutions below at the command line. The problem may be elsewhere in your code. Be careful when debugging scripts with `rm`! Test on a folder with copies of the files or fake files, and use `echo` in place of `rm` until you see the results you want.

Comment: I am using the users application as a test. The reason why I want to send it out via a script is because I am deploying it to numerous computers using a computer management software. I still can't seem to get it to work in the command line either.

Comment: Is the `grep` command really on its own line or does it come after the preceding pipe? How does it fail besides "not working"?

Comment: The grep command follows the preceding pipe. I'm not sure how it exactly fails as it doesn't provide me with any information on the failure and the management software seems to think the script ran successfully, however the applications remain. @beroe

Comment: @jww ls: /Users/laptop.7/Applications/Tableau*.app: No such file or directory.      Is the result I get, I've tried to putting parentheses around it, still no luck

Comment: `find "$HOME/Applications" -type f -not -name 'Tableu Reader 2019.2.app' -name 'Tableu Reader*' -exec echo rm {} +` what does this command output?

Comment: `find "$HOME/Applications" -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'` This part brings up all the applications apart from any related to Tableau? and then the rest of the command doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ls "tableau reader"* | sort | head -n -1 | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Comment: @Sharoze The `head` function here is not working on the contents of a file but on the output of the pipe that precedes it, which is the list of files.

Comment: versions
xargs: illegal option -- d
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
head: illegal line count -- -1
ls: tableau reader*: No such file or directory

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app' | grep "Tableau Reader" | xargs -I {} rm {}
```

The scripts finds all the files except with the name `Tableau Reader 2019.2.app` and from that using `grep` all files containing `Tableau Reader` are separated and then deletes it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I just tried it but it didn't work, it didn't give me an error but it also didn't do anything. I posted the full script I am using, maybe there is another fault?

Comment: @SharozeKhan I had tested the script with sample files and it worked. What does the output command shows `find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'  | grep "tableau reader" `

Comment: Although there doesn't seem to be an issue with the script, it runs as a complete. It just doesn't provide a result, the folders applications still remain, so I am not too sure whats happening. It's like it's just bypassing that line of code

Comment: What does the output command shows find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app' | grep "tableau reader". ------- This brings up no result. Nothing returns

Comment: @SharozeKhan What does the output command `find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'` shows? Also, I have seen from the edited post that the `tableau reader` is `Tableau Reader`. Also could you try grep with that (I have edited the answer)?

Comment: It brings up a list of all the applications in the users application folder and all the files within the applications. Including 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'

Comment: @SharozeKhan It should work though. I have tested this in my system with dummy files named `Tableau Reader`. Can you run it again without the `.app` extension. `find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2' | grep "Tableau Reader"`. Also I have changed the last part of the above answer. Anyway find should work.

Comment: Something weird is happening: find $HOME/Applications -type f -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2' | grep "Tableau Reader"  - I don't get any results when I run this, but when I remove the grep command, it returns all the apps in application(folder) apart from ANY Tableau apps? any of this seem correct?

Comment: @SharozeKhan That's weird. It should not contain the file `Tableau Reader 2019.2`, except that everything should be there. Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce the error in my system. I have created the same dummy files as yours in my system and the script worked as expected. One last thing, what does `ls $HOME/Applications` and `ls $HOME/Applications/Tableau*` outputs?

Comment: Yep, annoyingly weird! and They both output correctly what they should: `ls $HOME/Applications` outputs all applications and `ls $HOME/Applications/Tableau*` outputs only applications with tableau

Comment: @SharozeKhan That's pretty strange. As seen in some comments, the issue can be maybe it is a symbolic link. If find works then the remaining part of the script will work.

Comment: @SharozeKhan It can be due to symbolic link. If it is a link then it won't show. I created a link with the same name and it is not shown in the find.

Comment: `find -L $HOME/Applications -type l -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'` will shows the symbolic links except the  'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'`. So deleting the link wont suffice. ` ls -la ` can be used to check whether there is symbolic link. It will be denoted by the symbol` ->`

Comment: 'find -L $HOME/Applications -type l -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app' Still brings up Tableau Reader 2019.2.app followed by all the contents inside it? but also the symbol doesn't appear, I don't think they are symbolic links as when I enter `find -L $HOME/Applications` all applications show up including the tableau ones.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable with the `find` command only, but lets test it before it deletes something:

```sh
find "$HOME/Applications/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'Tableau Reader*.app' -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'
```

See if it returns the list of the files you want to delete only:

The list of files should look like this, with your home directory instead of `/tmp`:

```
/tmp/Applications/Tableau Reader 10.5.app
/tmp/Applications/Tableau Reader 2012.app
/tmp/Applications/Tableau Reader 10.3.app
/tmp/Applications/Tableau Reader 1.app
```

Lets see the options used to drive `find`:

- `find`: the command to find files
- `"$HOME/Applications/"`: the directory to start the search
- `-maxdepth 1`: stay in the directory, do not go into sub-directories
- `-type f`: find regular files
- `-name 'Tableau Reader*.app'`: find files with names matching this pattern
- `-not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app'` and not matching this other pattern

Now if you are satisfied with the list and are sure that you want to delete these files; `find` can do it for you if you add it the `-delete` option like this:

```sh
find "$HOME/Applications/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'Tableau Reader*.app' -not -name 'Tableau Reader 2019.2.app' -delete
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason this still didn't work for me, so I followed this step by step and I think I've found the issue. When I enter `find $HOME/Applications -maxdepth 1 -type f` It does not bring up any applications for me, just files for e.g `.DS_Store` and `.localized` and I think this is the reason why the line of code isn't working because it will not get to the stage of finding the actual TR apps, or any apps. Any idea what to do now?

Comment: Can you add a code text block output of `ls -la "$HOME/Applications/"`. I have the feeling that your `Tableau Reader...` are not actual files but symbolic links. This would explain why they are not found with `find -type f`.

Comment: Hi, This brings up all the files in applications correctly - including all the tableau versions. Does this mean I can't delete the different versions because they are symbolic links?

Comment: It means these are not your Tableau applications but symbolic links. If you remove these links, the applications will remain installed elsewhere. You need to follow the application uninstalation process for the Tableau application.

Comment: I don't believe these are symbolic links as the application is not installed elsewhere, also the tableau applications, along with the others appear when I enter this command `find - F $HOME/Applications`

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

`rm -f $(find . -name "tableau reader*" -type f -exec ls -t {} \; | head -n +2)`

Essentialy, run a subshell (as can be seen between `$(` and `)` to obtain what to remove.  Within that subshell, use `find` in the current directory only (`.`) with result type of file (`f`) exec an `ls` in time modified order using the `-t` flag.  Then pipe to `head` starting at the 2nd result (`-n +2`) (which ensures your latest file is excluded from the `rm` command.

Note - you have to be careful with `ls` though as you'll get strange results if filenames contain some special characters, but for your use-case it looks like it should be fine.

What I do with these tasks is copy some test files to a new directory to get my expression perfect before scripting it.  Make sure you use cp -a to preserve the file dates though.

Comment: Filenames have spaces! The `rm -f $(...)` will not work, filenames need to be properly passed.